# Performance of @Transactional over ProxyFactoryBean in Spring

Tags: java, spring, transactions

In my application, I have originally used ProxyFactoryBean to apply transaction to my DAO Beans as follows;

```
<bean id="buyProductDAO" class="com.trading.persistence.impl.jdbc.BuyProductDAOImpl" scope="prototype">
    <property name="jdbcTemplate">
        <ref bean="jdbcTemplate"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="buyProductDAOProxy" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
    <property name="proxyInterfaces">
        <value>com.trading.persistence.impl.jdbc.BuyProductDAO</value>
    </property>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>transactionInterceptor</value>
            <value>buyProductDAO</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In this case, if I discover proxy bean from my code, it will return me transactional bean. Also, currently, transactions applied at class level.

I thought to refactor my code to use @Transactionl. What would be the performance impact after conversion? I am planning to apply transaction at method level as opposite to the class level that currently implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ProxyFactoryBean` directly as a way of *Declarative Transaction Management* in Spring is a very old style that is not necessary any more.

[From the Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction-declarative):

> **Where is TransactionProxyFactoryBean?**
>
> Declarative transaction configuration in versions of Spring 2.0 and
>   above differs considerably from previous versions of Spring. The main
>   difference is that there is no longer any need to configure
>   TransactionProxyFactoryBean beans.
>
> The pre-Spring 2.0 configuration style is still 100% valid
>   configuration; think of the new  as simply defining
>   TransactionProxyFactoryBean beans on your behalf.

It seems you are already favoring [Declarative over Programmatic Transaction Management](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#tx-decl-vs-prog) (which is pretty much the standard these days) so there is no reason not to fully embrace `@Transactional` demarcation style.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How is the change impact for the performance?

Comment: As the Spring Doc is saying, the existing Spring tooling is initializing TransactionProxyFactoryBeans on your behalf. So on this area it's negligible if not on par. Performance considerations come primarily from things like: 1) non-optimal usage of your underlying persistence choice (spring-jdbc/orm/hibernate), 2) non-usage of DB Connection Pool, 3) inefficient batch ops etc

Answer (score 0):

firstly, i don't see targetObject being set in your bean definition(Proxy needs a target)

with your current configuration, all methods will be advised - transaction gets applied to all methods in your DAO class, similar to applying @Transactional at class level

When you will refactor your code to use @Transactional on a specific method, only those methods will be advised

Thats the only difference.